# What was Amos Diggory's job at the Ministry?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

In the Goblet of Fire we see Arthur talk about how Amos works with him at the Ministry. Does this mean that he works in the Misuse of Muggle Artifacts office as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the film, but in the source novel we learn that he works for the [*Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures*](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Department_for_the_Regulation_and_Control_of_Magical_Creatures).

> Mr Weasley was shaking hands with a ruddy-faced wizard with a scrubby brown beard, who was holding a mouldy-looking old boot in his other hand.
>   **‘This is Amos Diggory, everyone,’ said Mr Weasley. ‘Works for the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures.** And I think you know his son, Cedric?’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

Comment: I forgot that was even in the book as I had only seen the movie for GoF lol. Thanks for quick reference. I'll accept ASAP.

Comment: @NeoDarwin - I'm still trying to find out what he actually did in his dept. I *assumed* he was relatively senior in the Ministry but I can't find any actual evidence for it.

Comment: I would be really glad if you could find anything relating to that. I am writing a fic and if he actually was senior then it would help me in my writing.

Comment: *"Amos," said Mr. Crouch curtly, "I am fully aware that, in the ordinary course of events, you would want to take Winky into your department for questioning. I ask you, however, to allow me to deal with her." Mr. Diggory looked as though he didn't think much of this suggestion at all, but it was clear to Harry that Mr. Crouch was such an important member of the Ministry that he did not dare refuse him.* Seems like he was senior enough to have the authority to allow Winky to not be taken in, but not senior enough to stand up to Crouch (who was a department head).

Comment: @Valorum It seems like everyone in the Ministry is in middle management

Comment: @AzorAhai: Perhaps there's a separate division for that: the Ministry of Middle Management. Think of the alliteration!